# How to get the next element in a sparse array?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to get the next element of an array. For contiguous arrays, my code works just fine:

```
arr=(item{2..5})
value=item3

for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};++i)); do
    if [[ ${arr[i]} = "$value" ]] && (( i+1<${#arr[@]} )); then
        echo "${arr[i+1]}"
        break
    fi  
done
```

I didn't find any definition of how parameter expansion behaves on sparse arrays and this code unfortunately doesn't yield the desired result either:

```
arr=([3]=item2 [7]=item3 [10]=item4 [1]=item5)

for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};++i)); do
    if [[ ${arr[@]:i:1} = "$value" ]]; then
        ...
        ...
    fi
done
```

How can I do this for sparse arrays (possibly without the need to copy the array as to reindex it) ?

Comment: `echo "${!arr[@]}"`

Comment: @Cyrus If I loop over the indexes, I will have the same problem of finding the next index, won't I?

Comment: Your current code is looping over *potential* indices; `${!arr[@]}` is the *actual* set of indices.

Comment: @Cyrus From my previous questions you can see that I know what to do when I am satisfied with an answer. I was just waiting for someone else to possibly chime in ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=([3]=item2 [7]=item3 [10]=item4 [1]=item5)
value="item3"
switch="0"

# loop over array's indexes
for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
  if [[ $switch = "1" ]]; then
    echo "found ${arr[$i]} in element $i"
    switch="0"
    break
  fi

  if [[ ${arr[$i]} = "$value" ]]; then
    echo "found ${arr[$i]} in element $i"
    switch="1"
    continue
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
found item3 in element 7
found item4 in element 10
```

The script does not check whether the end of the array has already been reached.

---

See: `help continue`